# Why can't PacletFind["XXX"] or PacletObject["XXX"] not find my installed Paclet?

Tags: paclets

I have created a `paclet` whose `PacletInfo.wl` look like as follows:

```
PacletObject[<| 

    "Name" -> "XXX",
    "Version" -> "0.0.0.0.0001",
    "BuildDate" -> "Sun 7 Jan 2024 00:59:25",
    "BuildNumber" -> "1",
    "BuildWolframVersionNumber" -> "1",
    "BuildWolframLibraryVersion" -> "1",
    "Loading" -> "Manual",
    "Icon" -> "Assets/Images/PacletIcon.png",
    "Updating" -> "Automatic",
    "AutoUpdating" -> "True",
    "Enabled" -> "True",
    
    "MathematicaVersion" -> "13+",
    "WolframVersion" -> "13+",
    "Language" -> "English",
    "SystemID" -> "Windows-x86-64",
    "Qualifier" -> "Win64",
    "PlatformQualifier" -> "Win",
    "Root" -> ".",
    "PrimaryContext" -> "...`",
    
    "Creator" -> "...",
    "Description" -> "...",
    "Category" -> "...",
    "Keywords" -> {"...", "..."},
    "DocumentationURL" -> "",
    "URL" -> "",
    "Support" -> "...",
    "Published" -> "...",
    "PublisherID" -> "...",
    "Publisher" -> "...",
    "Transport" -> "PacletSite",
    "Internal" -> "True",
    "License" -> "Proprietary and confidential",
    
    "Extensions" -> {
        {
            "Kernel",
            
            "MathematicaVersion" -> "13+",
            "WolframVersion" -> "13+",
            "Language" -> "English",
            "SystemID" -> "Windows-x86-64",
            "Qualifier" -> "Win64",
            "PlatformQualifier" -> "Win",
            "Root" -> "Kernel",
            "Context" -> {"...`", "...`"},
            
            "Symbols" -> {
            }
        },
        {
            "Asset",
            
            "MathematicaVersion" -> "13+",
            "WolframVersion" -> "13+",
            "Language" -> "English",
            "SystemID" -> "Windows-x86-64",
            "Qualifier" -> "Win64",
            "PlatformQualifier" -> "Win",
            "Root" -> "Binaries",
            
            "Assets" -> {
                {"Executable", "..."},
                {"DLL32Bit", "..."},
                {"DLL64Bit", "..."}
            }
        }
    }
|>]
```

I am able to `PacletInstall["XXX"]` and use the functions inside the paclet after calling `Needs["..."]`.

But when I try `PacletFind["XXX"]` or `PacletObject["XXX"]`, it finds nothing. Clearly this is false since the paclet is certainly installed and I am able to use it and also see it in `$UserBasePacletsDirectory\Repository`. Can some please help if I am missing some field or using an incorrect value in the `PacletInfo.wl` file which is causing `PacletFind["XXX"]` or `PacletObject["XXX"]` to not find it after installation. May be a key `"Discoverable" -> "True"`?

Comment: Perhaps remove `"Internal" -> "True"`

Comment: @ilian Thank you it works! By the way, many of the `PacletObject` fields inside `PacletInfo.wl` are missing from the official `Tutorial` page and the `Symbol` page for `PacletObject`. You guys should make a special reference page for `PacletInfo.wl` fields or list all of them on `PacletObject` page and whether they are `Inert` or `Active` and if they are `Active` list exactly how they affect the rest of `Paclet` system.